# How is the fractional part of the mantissa represented?

Tags: floating-point, double, precision

When many people try to explain floating-point number representation, the break it down into three parts:

1. Sign bit indicating negative or positive
2. Exponent indicating the scale (e.g. 8)
3. Mantissa indicating the base (e.g. 1.2345)

I understand that these values are treated as integers in a single 64 bit address (for doubles). What I have not seen explained is how you would represent a mantissa of 1.2345 in binary format when computers know nothing about the decimal separator or where it should be *"placed"* within the mantissa.

I am looking for a complete step-by-step explanation of how I would construct a (32 bit if you want) floating point representation of a decimal number and vice versa.

Comment: The exponent is all about where the binary point should be placed.

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes a binary format.

Except for a few special cases, (0 and subnormal numbers), the significand *m* (the technical name: a [mantissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantissa) is a similar but slightly different concept) is in the interval 1 ≤ *m* < 2, so the leading digit doesn't need to be stored (since it is always 1).

The remaining bits give the fractional part, stored as binary. You can think of this as subtracting off decreasing powers of 2:

1. 0.2345 < 2<sup>-1</sup>, so the first bit is 0
2. 0.2345 < 2<sup>-2</sup>, so the second bit is 0
3. 0.2345 ≥ 2<sup>-3</sup>, so the third bit is 1

   - 0.2345 - 2<sup>-3</sup> = 0.1095
4. 0.1095 ≥ 2<sup>-4</sup>, so the 4th bit is 1

   - 0.1095 - 2<sup>-4</sup> = 0.047
5. 0.047 ≥ 2<sup>-5</sup>, so the 5th bit is 1

   - 0.047 - 2<sup>-5</sup> = 0.01575

etc. continuing this process gives you the expansion

00111100000010000011000100100110111010010111100011010100111111...

(from [Rick Regan's decimal/binary converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/))

For a double this is rounded to 52 bits (or 53 if you count the implicit leading 1):

0011110000001000001100010010011011101001011110001101

Answer (score -1):

Actually, decimal point is not stored in number's float or double representation. You are right about three parts of floating point number representation, but there are some important nuances:

1. First bit indicates sign - `0` for positive value, `1` for negative.
2. Exponent is in base 2 instead of base 10, so that `3` means `23` instead of `103`. In case of 32-bit floats we have 8 bits for exponent, with `10000000` assumed as zero, this gives us exponents between -128 and 127 (we can encode numbers from `2-128` to `2127` using them).
3. Mantissa (or significand) is stored in scientific notation, which means it is between `[0, 1)`, or greater or equal to `0` and less than `1`. This way we don't have to store `0.` part, i.e. `0.1234` can be stored as `1234`.

Now, how the above is stored in actual floating point number. Let's have a look at example, say, we have a number `x = 123.456`.

1. It is positive, so the sign bit is 0.
2. Now we look for `y` - smallest power of `2`, so that `0 <= x/y < 1`. In our case it is `128` (or `27`): `123.456 / 128 = 0.9645`, which gives us exponent equal to `7` or `00000111` in binary.
3. Now we have to encode `0.9645` but we don't need to actually store `0.` part. As you may now, decimal part of a number is represented in binary as a negative power of 2 counting from the left, i.e. `0.1101` in binary means `1 * 2-1 + 1 * 2-2 + 0 * 2-3 + 1 * 2-4 = 1/2 + 1/4 + 0 + 1/16 = 0.5 + 0.25 + 0.0625 = 0.8125`. This is how we convert our `0.9645` to binary - we recursively subtract negative powers of 2 from it until we have 0 or run out of bits (this is where precision issues raise): `0.9645 - 2-1 - 2-2 - 2-3 - 2-4 - 2-6 - ...`, or `0.111101...` in binary. Looking ahead, `0.9645` is `0.11110110111010010111100` in base 2 with 23-bit precision (this many bits are left out of 32 after we took 1 for sign and 8 for exponent).

Wrap up, and we get following floating-point representation of our initial number `123.456`:

```
    0 00000111 11110110111010010111100
    ^     ^               ^
    |     |               |
    |     |               +--- significand = 0.9644999504089356 ~ 0.9645
    |     |
    |     +------------------- exponent = 7
    |
    +------------------------- sign = 0 (positive)
```

Comment: With this scheme, 123.456 and 124.456 would have the same bit representation, right? How do you store the difference to 2^y?